# if the value of $R^2$ in linear regression analysis is 1.0, is it good or bad? What are the alternatives?

Tags: regression

[image: the SPSS output of linear regression]

The picture shows my results. I have reviewed all the row data many times. Unfortunately, I couldn't find mistakes in data entry. Are there any possible solutions or alternatives in such cases?

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other answers have mentioned, more background information on your data is needed to draw a reliable conclusion.

With that being said, an **R<sup>2</sup>** value of **1** does mean that your model is potentially "too good to be true" as another answer mentioned.

From your output, I am assuming that your regression is of the **Ordinary Least Squares** form. I would be inclined to do the following:

- Run a **Variance Inflation Factor** test on your independent variables to test for **multicollinearity**. This is where two or more independent variables have a strong correlation (and could be theoretically linked). Therefore, the dependent variable is accounting for the effect of this multiple times, but your R<sup>2</sup> value is still rising, giving an overly optimistic result. It may be the case that you need to drop certain multi-collinear variables if the theoretical nature (or lack of it) behind them justifies doing so.
- If your data is a **time series** one, then it is possible that a trend in your data is producing a high R-Squared due to high correlations between the dependent and independent variables, even when this is likely due to the trend which does not have any theoretical foundation. I would be inclined to test your model for **autocorrelation** (if indeed your data is time series, if not ignore this step) using a Durbin-Watson test, and if this problem is present then try first differencing the values and run the regression again.

Overall, an **R<sup>2</sup>** value of **1** - while possible - indicates perfect collinearity and certainly warrants further investigation before a conclusion can be drawn.

Comment: This is wrong. Multicollinearity should have no effect to R2. http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/what-are-the-effects-of-multicollinearity-and-when-can-i-ignore-them

Comment: @StudentT Having more variables present than necessary in the model will result in overfitting. So if one were to remove the multicollinear variable, the R-squared value would be likely to drop.

Comment: The link says "Multicollinearity doesn’t affect how well the model fits.".  Multicollinearity affects coefficient estimates but not prediction power such as R2.

Comment: @StudentT Multicollinearity doesn't affect model fit, but including more variables than necessary in a regression equation, ie. Multicollinear variables, does. It is known as overfitting. A high r^2 is not caused by -  but is a consequence of - multicollinearity.

Answer (score 4):

In general a better $R^2$ is good (given that you aren't making your model too complex; this is what the adjusted $R^2$ value is for). However, $R^2=1$ means that for some reason your model predicts the response variable *perfectly*, which is generally too good to be true. Common reasons are:

- you have some kind of artificial data (e.g. made up for a homework exercise)
- you are overfitting (using a model that is too complex); this is probably not the current situation, since you have 136 observations and 8 predictor variables
- you messed up something about your data analysis (e.g. you're accidentally predicting something that you meant to be one of the predictor variables)

It's hard to say more without more context about what your variables are and why you're doing the analysis.

Comment: Thank you, Ben, regarding the 1st point the data is real, unfortunately :( but my observation that most of the answers are at extreme (5)

Comment: for the 2nd point, i have merged the variables into 3, and same results come up!

Comment: if possible to share the data with you along with the main topic of my study, i do believe that you can help. thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

An $R^2=1$ means that the data is perfectly correlated.  This is reflected in your standard errors being $0$.

When performing linear regression, you want the value of $R^2$ to be as close to $1$ as possible, although there are times that a much lower $R^2$ value can be acceptable.